# How many telegram bots can I create?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is there a limit to the number of bots a user can create on telegram?

I'm considering "selling custom bots" to people as a service, and would like to avoid having my clients handle technical stuff like api keys or "talking to botfather". So I would create their bot on my account, but this isn't really doable if I'm limited to a certain number of bots.
I didn't find anything in their docs or their faq, but maybe someone here did run into a limit.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can only create **20 bots** per Telegram account. Although it‘s not written in [Bot FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq), but proved by many bot developers.

Comment: what if someone deletes their bots, will that reset the limit?

Comment: @code-aesthete Yes, you can create a bot after deleted another.

Comment: Also, you can create only 5 bots in the last 24h interval. Telegram says: "Sorry, too many attempts. Please try again in 84818 seconds"

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the official Telegram website (where you can find all other limits)

https://limits.tginfo.me/en

The max number of bots you can create is 20.