# Telegram: Is it possible to have different names in different groups/channles?

Tags: telegram

Is it possible to use the same user, but configure a different display name for different groups/channles?

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, you can't do this at this time. Work account is on the roadmap.

You might want to use [bot account](https://core.telegram.org/bots/), one human account can manage [20 bots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46726858/5201431), and they can have a different name, profile photo.